# WIFI USB adapter - Sitecom WLA-3001 AC450 instalation

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm new to Ubuntu and I try to figure everything out by reading this forum.
But right now I have a problem and I can't find a good manual on Google.

I know its possible to use the "WIFI USB adapter - Sitecom WLA-3001 AC450" on Ubuntu but I have no idea how to make it work
Here is a link to the wifi adapter I bought: https://www.sitecom.com/en/wi-fi-usb...la-3001/p/1657

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0402:7675 ALi Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Can someone please help me?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: The only device we see in `lsusb` is a webcam. Please be sure the wifi is inserted and try again.

Comment: thnx chili555 but I'm realy a newby, how do I make the wifi inserted?

Comment: I mean, my wifi adapter is inserted, but is there anything else I should do?